# Is it possible to run webservice based on SOAPpy with mod_wsgi under Apache?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, soappy

Is it possible to run webservice based on SOAPpy with mod_wsgi under Apache?
if yes can you post link to sample(example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SOAPpy has its own HTTP server based on `BaseHTTPServer` which means that it is not possible to turn it into a WSGI app without a non-trivial amount of hacking.